# Using Selenium to locate element in iframe

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

Using this site:
(https://buyee.jp/mercari/search?keyword=seiko%20S-212&status=on_sale) or see the html below:

[HTML with Element of Interest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCKAB.png)

I'm trying to locate the element that has the value: "Items 1 to 2", please see screenshot below:

[image]

I tried locating the element by xpath, my full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

val = 'https://buyee.jp/mercari/search?keyword=seiko%20S-212&status=on_sale'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(val)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

items = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]')
```

However I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/auto.py", line 10, in <module>
    items = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]')
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/kali/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 741, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/kali/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/kali/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:187:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:505:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:135:16


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What is the relevant HTML code? Add it to your original question, no comment. I get a HTTP error 404 because there's some IP filtering. Always post a   
MCVE aka [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I added the html as a screenshot in the original question.

Comment: [Do not upload images of input/code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Use plain text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page use an [iframe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames).

So, this is a working code with valid XPath:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

val = 'https://buyee.jp/mercari/search?keyword=seiko%20S-212&status=on_sale'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(val)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

iframe = driver.find_element(By.ID, "search_result_iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe) # mandatory to change the context

# need to be improved:
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
import time
time.sleep(10) 
  
# the relevant XPath query, searching by text
item = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Items 1 to 2"]')
print(item.text)

# back to main page
driver.switch_to.default_content()

driver.quit()
```